Flutter Web: How to convert HEIC to JPEG?
I was trying to compress the image before sending it to the server. But HEIC format images cannot be compressed using the package (flutter_image_compress). Also, I did not find a package that can convert images for Flutter Web. What other options are there?
I tried to find a way to do this without using third-party packages but couldn't find one.

Have you try heif_converter?

No, it only lists Android and iOS platforms. As far as I know, the web is not supported.

"I was trying to compress the image before sending it to the server" - HEIC is already compressed image, much better then JPEG (in most cases it can use as little as half the space that a JPEG file would)

Since Flutter Web doesn't have a direct way to convert photos, I used the package "heic2any" for JavaScript.
Update index.html file (./web/index.html)
<!-- HEIC to any converter -->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/heic2any"></script>
<script>
  async function convertHeicToJpeg(heicFile) {
    try {
      const convertedBlob = await heic2any({
        blob: heicFile,
        toType: "image/jpeg",
      });
      return convertedBlob;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("HEIC to JPEG conversion failed:", error);
      throw error;
    }
  }
</script>

My HeicToJpegService code:
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:html'; // for using Blob
import 'dart:js_util' as js_util;
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:js/js.dart';

@JS('convertHeicToJpeg')
external Future<Blob> convertHeicToJpegBlob(Blob heicFile);

class HeicToJpegService {
  /// Convert Blob to Uint8List
  Future<Uint8List> _blobToUint8List(Blob blob) async {
    final completer = Completer<Uint8List>();
    final reader = FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
    reader.onLoadEnd.listen((event) {
      completer.complete(Uint8List.fromList(reader.result as List<int>));
    });
    reader.onError.listen((event) {
      completer.completeError(reader.error ?? 'Unknown error');
    });
    return completer.future;
  }

  Future<Uint8List> convertHeicToJpeg(Uint8List fileBytes) async {
    final blob = Blob([fileBytes]);
    final convertedBlob = await js_util.promiseToFuture<Blob>(
      js_util.callMethod(window, 'convertHeicToJpeg', [blob]),
    );
    return await _blobToUint8List(convertedBlob);
  }
}

This code works as expected. There are no problems with it either.

In flutter web there is no direct way to do that till now. You can do it by implementing javascript in index.html or you can use server side logic to convert heic to jpeg format.
